# Using Parameters httpClient and generated Url in request in Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, url

Iam using httpGet to access Lumen web api server with 4 parameters in angular 4, this is my web api url : http://sismonev.api/member/2017/8, they have 2 parameter year and month and member key. in my angular4 component bellow my code :

```
 let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('tahun', '2017');
    params = params.append('bulan', '5');

   this.http.get<JuResponse>(environment.url + '/member', {params: params})
              .subscribe(data => {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        let pd=+data[i].jumlah; // comvert to number
                          this.pieD.push(pd);
                          this.pieChartLabels.push(data[i].jenis_bu);
                      }
                      this.pieChartData=this.pieD;
                      console.log(this.pieChartData);
                  },
                  err => {
                      console.log("Error occured.")
                  });
```

this not working, because angular generated like this :

```
http://sismonev.api/member?year=2017&month=8
```

Lumen web api give the error like this :

```
NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 596:
```

Could anyone give me explanation? how to generate url to access web api with this `http://sismonev.api/member/2017/8` format.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Parameters added with params are added as [query parameters](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters).

```
const url = "member";
const year = 2017;
const month = 8;
this.http.get<JuResponse>(environment.url + `/${member}/${year}/${month}`)
```

Also check [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @YK.toe Please check edited answer or provide details what you mean with dynamicaly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `year` and `month` are variables.

```
let year = '2017';
let month = '8';
this.http.get<JuResponse>(`&{environment.url}/member/${year}/${month}`)
```

function could be something like:

```
getPieChartDateFor(month:string, year:string){...}
```

Comment: thank Venomy, not working, url generated being sismonev.api/memberNaN.

Comment: solved by stupid way : `          this.http.get<JuResponse>(environment.url + '/member/' + year + '/' + month)
`